# Allow only 2 users to read an object from a public class

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I'm building a private chat between 2 users.  Currently I've got the "Chat" class open to everyone (read/write) and there is where all messages (objects) go.

I was thinking about adding objects with permission to read only between two users so only they can see what they chat.

I'm grabbing the messages using:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

PFQuery *fquery = [PFUser query]; // query to get the chat partener
[fquery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"friendid"]];
PFUser *friend = (PFUser *)[fquery getFirstObject];    // got it!

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"]; // new query for grabbing messages
[query whereKey:PF_CHAT_ROOM equalTo:chatroom]; // @"Chat" = @"Chat"
if (message_last != nil) [query whereKey:PF_CHAT_CREATEDAT greaterThan:message_last.date]; 
[query includeKey:PF_CHAT_USER]; // current user
[query includeKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", friend]]; // its friend/partener
[query orderByAscending:PF_CHAT_CREATEDAT]; // sort by date
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
// adding the messages to an array;
 }];
```

For writing messages to parse:

```
PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Chat"]; // class name
object[PF_CHAT_ROOM] = chatroom; 
object[PF_CHAT_USER] = [PFUser currentUser];
object[PF_CHAT_TEXT] = text;

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"friendid"]];
PFUser *friend = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];  // query to get the chat partener

PFACL *roleACL = [PFACL ACL];
[roleACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[roleACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:friend];  // setting read permission for those guys

object.ACL = roleACL;
[object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
{ 
    ....
}];
```

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a similar app taking the same approach which seemed to work. But I think you've over complicated for what it needs to be.

You need a Chat class which you seem to have. This may be something similar to:

```
Chat
Object ID, Message, Author, Date, Date Seen, ACL, etc.... 
(there's many good schemas out there just google it)
```

Then when you create a new chat message to a friend you simply just create a new PFObject setting the other user's ACL permission to like you've done correctly.

The user can read his messages by calling

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
```

The response of the query will only be the chats that the user has read permission to, not everyones. Therefore there's no need to specify any further query parameters unless you're looking for unread messages, etc..